# Python: If Statement For Reading Txt Files

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
print "Note: Your file is available now."
viewYourFile = raw_input("\nDo you wish to view this file now? ")

if viewYourFile == 'Y' or 'y':
    fo = open('messages.txt', 'r+')
    #Read whole file into data
    data = fo.read()
    print data
    # Close the file
    fo.close()
elif viewYourFile == 'N' or 'n': 
    print "Thank you!"
else:
    print "Didn't recognize user input"
```

When I type in 'n' the text file still opens. If the user types in 'N' or 'n' I want the script to move on without printing the text into the terminal.

I can't spot anything obvious that I've done wrong. Can someone take a second look for me? Many thanks.

Comment: @BubbleMonster if you get answer select one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if viewYourFile == 'Y' or 'y':` always evaluates to `True` since the second condition `'y'` is always `True`.

```
>>> bool('y')
True
>>> bool(False or 'y')
True
```

Use `if viewYourFile in ('Y', 'y'):` instead.

Also, instead of closing the file manually, use `with` context manager. Here's the resulting code:

```
print "Note: Your file is available now."
viewYourFile = raw_input("\nDo you wish to view this file now? ")

if viewYourFile in ('Y', 'y'):
    with open('messages.txt', 'r+') as fo:
        data = fo.read()
elif viewYourFile in ('N', 'n'): 
    print "Thank you!"
else:
    print "Didn't recognize user input"
```

Also see:

- [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah)

Comment: Thanks that works. Can you explain why that evaluates to true but it doesn't using brackets?

Comment: @BubbleMonster you are welcome, see updated answer, hope it's clear.

Comment: @BubbleMonster also see explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah

Comment: Thanks yes that makes sense, however, when I do: with open('messages.txt', 'r+') as fo  - I get an error: Invalid syntax. Not too sure why.

Comment: @BubbleMonster oh, sorry, missed colon, edited, give it a try.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
if viewYourFile == 'Y' or viewYourFile == 'y':
```

or as like [@alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18635516/939986) suggested, i.e.:

```
if viewYourFile in ('Y', 'y'):
```

Another good way that includes less typing is:

```
if viewYourFile.lower() == 'y':
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh. Voted up for that info. Wasn't aware that I would have to declare the variable twice using one parameter!

Answer (score 1):

More smarter I think lead to one register:

```
if viewYourFile.lower() == 'y':
```